# COM device communication

Tags: c#, serial-port

I need to send commands to my COM device. When I work with HyperTerminal it works great like:

> on
>   sd 1 255 255 9 100 255 0
>   of

and it works great... But when I run my console C# code like this:

```
var port = new SerialPort(SerialPort.GetPortNames()[0], 115200);
        port.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSendXOnXOff;
        port.Open();
        port.WriteLine("on");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        port.WriteLine(sd 1 255 255 9 100 255 0);
        Console.ReadLine();
        port.WriteLine("of");
        port.Close();
```

Nothing happens :( What's the problem? I've tryed all of Handshakes - still nothing.

Comment: First of all make sure `SerialPort.GetPortNames()[0]` is the same port you have in Hyper Terminal, nect make sure you use the same baudrate, bitcount, parity and handshake as with HyperTerminal. Post these values and how you set them in your code.

Comment: Artem, when you write "I've tryed all of Handshakes - still nothing" and also say you made sure, you have the same handshake as in HyperTerminal, you make it quite hard for the SO community to help you.

Comment: Make sure you are sending CR-LF after your command

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of an oscilloscope capturing the data signal from the (successfuly) HyperTerminal connection, with the time divisions labelled?

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler  `oscilloscope`? A device all software developers use while coding :)

Comment: @L.B. Well, it looks like the dude is transmitting simple commands to an external device, quite possibly writing data to a microcontroller, so I'm wagering he has an oscope handy.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler, OK wait and see

Comment: What is CR-LF? No, I can't provide screen in some reasons, unfortunately :( ...

Comment: @Artem "\r\n" is a CR-LF: carriage return (0x0A), line feed (0x0D).  It's what gets transmitted when you hit the return/enter key during most connections.

Comment: But doesn't "WriteLine" command send this automatically?

Comment: It might work better when you put double quotes around the string.

Comment: @Artem Makarov: The documentation for "SerialPort.WriteLine" says that it sends "SerialPort.NewLine", and the documentation for _that_ says "The default is a line feed".

Comment: What you are doing in the code vs the terminal is 2 different things...

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler: Oscilloscopes are only for people that dont know what they are doing :) (j/k)

Comment: @Artem: Oh, I mixed up CR and LF in my haste.  CR is 0x0D, LF is 0x0A.  My bad.

Comment: Thank you all! The problem was really with "\r\n" in the end of commands. I thought that it's the same as WriteLine. Thanks again!

Comment: @ArtemMakarov: If you found the answer, you should add it as an answer to your own question, then accept that answer.  That way, this will no longer show up in the list of unanswered questions.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are sending CR-LF ("\r\n"):  carriage return (0x0A), line feed (0x0D) after your command